# How can I get the HTTP request data?

Tags: java, jmeter, httprequest

I'm testing with JMeter and I need the HTTP request data to make that.

I tried to see that information in F12 Network of Chrome browser, but it doesn't appear the information there.

Someone knows how can I get that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the request because the browser refreshes the network tab when you go to another page. But you can persist these requests marking the option `Preserve Logs`, like so:

**Image before request, with the checkbox checked:**

[image: Image before the request]

**After request, persistent logs:**
[image]

You can see more information about the `network tab` [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/)

Comment: I liked the red draw lines. It was really explicative.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to capture [HAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.har) file in the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://www.inflectra.com/support/knowledgebase/kb254.aspx), it will have all the information for the request data including parameters, headers, cookies, etc.

[image: Chrome save HAR]

Once done you will be able to inspect it with i.e. [HAR Analyzer](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/) or [simply convert it into a JMeter .jmx script](http://converter.blazemeter.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to capture HTTP Requests is by using [JMeter's Proxy.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

If you  try to inspect network in browser and construct JMeter script manually it takes lot of efforts, Alternatively you can just set your JMeter as a proxy server and capture your browsers network traffic.

Follow this post for more information on how to [setup proxy in JMeter](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/) and record web applications.